# How can i fix 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have some code when i debugging this "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." appear. How can i fix this error?

Here is my coding :

```
Private Sub StartWebCam()
    Try
        StopWebcam()
        MyWebcam = New WebCamCapture
        MyWebcam.Start(0)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub StopWebcam()
    Try
        MyWebcam.Stop()
        MyWebcam.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

The error appear at "MyWebcam.Stop()". Someone pls help me..

Comment: Whenever you receive such an error, the first thing to do is debug your code and find what's null (nothing). Simply inspect the variables on the line that throws the error. Once you know what is null, you need to figure out why it is and either add a conditional check to not use it while it's null (if being null is valid in some cases) or ensure that it is never null before it's used.

Answer (score 0):

`MyWebCam` is not intialized when you call the method `StopWebCam()`.

You can initialize it first and pass it as an argument to the function. I am not well-versed with VB.NET but this is how it should look generally.

```
Private Sub StartWebCam()
    Try
        MyWebcam = New WebCamCapture
        StopWebcam(MyWebCam)
        MyWebcam.Start(0)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub StopWebcam(webcam)
    Try
        webcam.Stop()
        webcam.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Also, there is no need to call `Dispose()` in `StopWebCam` function. It doesnot guarantee that the CLR object will be disposed immediately. Let the Garbage collector do its job.

There are definitely other problems with code too, such as the webcam should be a class level variable instead of a local variable. If you want to keep it ia local variable, then there is no need to call `StopWebCam()` from `StartWebCam` because you are creating a new object everytime.

Comment: Please don't put empty Catch blocks in answers. It might encourage bad habits.